# how to extract data from mongodb using node red with condition that no duplicate data and it should pass every 30sec

Tags: mongodb, node-red, litmus

MTLinki doesn’t support MQTT protocol for extraction of the data, although there are 2 ways to extract data from MTLinki database so i m using mongodb

1. i m using nodered in manufacturing connect edge
2. to extract Fanuc Server DB at every 30  using mongo db connection
3. then  convert this data into the output JSON format
4. i need entire architecture with all sort of coding
5. i have host name , port , username, psrwd, database name and collection name

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't just provide solutions based on a list of requirements. You need to show what you've tried and explain how it didn't work, then we will help you fix it.